# indexing text resources on windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I have about 500 text files (around 6 MB overall) i need to use as resources in my windows phone application.

My application is searching for a string given by the user in the resources and returns the files containing the string to be displayed to the user.

I´m looking for the right way to do this kind of search, i have 3 ideas:

1. Iterate the files on every search, use String.Contains to find the given string.
2. Pre-load the files to the memory, iterate them on every search (it is in memory but takes around 6 MB).
3. Use some kind of a local document db (any ideas?) to index the files for a textual search.

Comment: This would likely be much better done on a server with an actual full text engine and passing back results. Your app won't have the resources to do a proper full text search I would imagine (I would suspect you'll encounter out of memory exceptions). A contains type search will give you the absolute basic type text search only. I'm not sure if it's compatible, but have a look at Lucene for .NET.

Comment: Thanks! we chose not to implement a server side for this app, it most be a standalone version with no need for internet

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is you can use the local database `SQLite`, this is a [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Using-Sqlite-with-WP8-52c3c671).